# Removing the onsubmit value from a form with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some forms with onsubmit="return false;", example:

```
<form id="form-nr-56" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
formstuff
</form>
```

If certain conditions are met, i will submit the form by javascript

```
$('#form-id').submit();
```

But i need to remove the onsubmit="return false;" from the form in question first.

How to do that?

EDIT: Im not using javascript check in the onsubmit because the form verification is using alot of ajax requests and also a setTimeout, so it would always return false.

Comment: [Remove Attr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) as suggested by Danny will work for you, however its not the right way, you should be checking it inside your `submit` whether to return false or not.

Comment: yes i usually do that, i was just hesistant of doing it since the validator of the form does several ajaxrequests and waits for an SMS to come to the server from the customer, so i was thinking it would fail to return true after such a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here on jquery.com docs: http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

That answer's your technical question. Some of the other replies on here answer it on a more logical approach, other ways that may be better to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    if(//your codition here)
    {
       $('#form-id').submit();
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

    //write your conditions and return false if not valid other wise otherwise 

   function example()
   {
       if your condition false 
        return false;

       $('#form-id').submit();

   }  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do what you want before the form submits
}
```

Try this & check.

Comment: this does not answer the question. read it again - OP is *deliberately* not using "onsubmit".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add `onSubmit = "return false;"`

You can do it as below,

```
$('#form-id').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var isTrue = false;

    //conditions.
    //set isTrue = true on all conditions validation.
    //and then return isTrue.
    return isTrue;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to stop the submit, then add your logic.

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```